# Запросом отбросить 1 максимальное и 1 минимальное значение

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Имеется таблица

col1 col2 col3  col4

1........2.......2....A

2........5......19...B

3........6.......0....C

4........7.......0....D

5........0.......0....E

Суть запроса такова,что надо отбросить отбросить максимальное и минимальное значение каждого столбца и подсчитать AVG, а затем результатом получить: (col1+col2)*col3

0 не учитывать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> надо отбросить отбросить максимальное и минимальное значение каждого столбца и подсчитать AVG

```
SELECT (SUM(field) - MAX(field) - MIN(field)) / (COUNT(field) - 2)
```